# How to link statically a Delphi procedure in a C++Builder project

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I want to link statically a Delphi function from a C++Builder source.  I added the .pas file to the C++Builder project.  I tried the following declarations:

In Delphi:

```
procedure SayHi; stdcall;
```

In C++Builder:

```
extern "C" {
    void __stdcall SayHi();
}
```

All modules compile fine, but when I link it I get the following error:

```
[ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'SayHi' referenced from C:\DEV\PACKSWAP\WIN64\DEBUG\MAIN.O
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you compile a `.pas` file in a C++Builder project, an `.hpp` header file is automatically created that you can then `#include` in your C++ code where needed.  There is no need to declare the function manually.

The linker error is due to your use of `extern "C"` on the C++ side.  That is affecting how the C++ compiler emits name mangling/decoratation for that function, so it does not match the name mangling/decoration that the Delphi compiler emits.  That is why the linker cannot find the function implementation.  Remove the `extern "C"` and then both compilers should emit the same name mangling/decoration to allow the linker to match them up.